# Windows 10 TPM failing to boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, dell-precision, tpm

I have a TPM Module on an old Dell Precision T5400 which I am trying to enable under Windows 10.  Unfortunately, windows is hanging on boot at the splash screen after I enable TPM in the BIOS.  Does TPM need to be enabled (and activated) prior to installing Windows, specifically win10?  I have tried several steps to enable it and none of them are working.  I started with a Win7 install then upgraded to 10 and would rather not do a fresh install if there is a way around this - especially if I will get the same result.  I've also applied driver firmware update from Dell to upgrade TPM 1.2 to 2.0

Attempts thus far:
1) Enable TPM in bios without activating - Won't boot
2) Enable TPM in bios plus activate - Won't boot
3) Disable and deactivate TPM - Boots successfully

Answer (score 0):

Just enabling a TPM should not make windows unbootable, enabling secure boot would do this. However then it wouldn't even reach the windows bootloader and I don't think this particular model has UEFI and thus no secure boot either.
So not sure what does activating there do, but only enabling tpm doesn't change how the os boots normally. Try to boot in safe mode after enabling tpm.